# Meaning of $t \mapsto \phi_t(x)$

Tags: functions, notation

The context may well be of assistance:

> 3. Consider a differential equation $x'=f(x)$. Assume that $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ is continuously differentiable. Denote by $\color{red}{t\mapsto\phi_t(x)}$ the solution to the differential equation $$\frac{d}{dt}\phi_t(x)=f(\phi_t(x)),\;\phi_0(x)=x.$$ Show that $\phi_{t+s}(x)=\phi_t(\phi_s(x))$ for all $s,t\ge0$ so that $\phi_{t+s}(x)$ is defined. This is called the *flow* property.

Answer (score 0):

The notation is indicating that we are thinking of the expression $\phi_t(x)$ as a function of $t$ (with $x$ fixed; or rather that there is a family of functions of $t$ parameterized by $x$).  The notation is read "$t$ maps to $\phi_t(x)$."  One may also see something such as "Define $g_x:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ by $t\mapsto \phi_t(x)$ to be the solution to the differential equation."

Comment: Do you mean $x$ parameterised by $t$?

Comment: In other words $x=x(t)$?

Comment: No, I do mean for $x$ to be fixed.  In the excerpt, you have $\phi_0(x)=x$, so the family of functions is parameterized by the starting point $x$.